# UICollectionView - Exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I'm creating `UIViewController` that contains a `UICollectionView` this is all setup in the storyboard, delegates and outlets I believe to be correct. In the `UIViewController` I have implemented the following methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In addition to the above the storyboard includes a `UICollectionViewCell` that is defined in a separate class. This is all working perfectly and the CollectionView is displaying data as expected.

But... I want a create a separate class that implements `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods and I've cut and pasted the methods from above that were in the `UIViewController` class into a separate datasource class. I'm then setting the UICollectionViews delegate and datasource to point to the new class. This results in the following exception :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

I have tried adding the new class as an `NSObject` in the storyboard and connecting the collection view, and also programmatically in the ViewDidLoad method in the ViewController same exception with both. Also the exception is being generated before ViewDidLoad, the ViewController is the root view controller.

Am I missing something, googling suggests that the collection view initWithCollectionViewLayout is required but how is this achieved when the CollectionView is being initialized in the StoryBoard and why does it work when it's methods are in the ViewController class?

One final point this is using xCode 6 Beta 5, in a perfect world I'd try this in xCode 5 but I'm migrating the data source to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

After all that typing I discovered that it was a silly typo, I'd made the datasource class a subclass of UICollectionView instead of NSObject.